Nextjs 14 Socket.io with Custom Server
I am currently developing a Next.js 14 application that incorporates Socket.io and "next custom server". The development process was guided by the example provided on the official Socket.io website: https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-nextjs.
While the application functions correctly on my local development server, I encounter issues with the socket functionalities upon deployment; only the Next.js routing and client-side code are working (I suppose it is due to Next Custom Server not supported). I have attempted deployments on both Vercel and Google Cloud Run without success.
Could anyone provide guidance on the appropriate deployment strategies or hosting environments that support "Socket.io/Custom Server" within a Next.js application? Any insights or suggestions you could offer would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time and assistance.
I've developed a Next.js 14 application using Socket.io and a custom server setup, following the configuration example from the official Socket.io website. Locally, everything runs as expected: the server handles both the Next.js routing and the Socket.io communications seamlessly.
For deployment, I tried hosting the application on Vercel and Google Cloud Run, expecting that the deployment would mirror the local setup where both the routing and socket communications are functional. However, upon deployment, I noticed that while the Next.js routing and client-side operations work correctly, the socket functionalities do not. I suspect this issue might be related to the hosting services not fully supporting the custom server setup required by Socket.io within a Next.js environment.
This discrepancy between the local functionality and the deployed version's behavior is puzzling, and I am looking for insights on how to resolve or work around this deployment issue.

From the Next.js documentation:
Before deciding to use a custom server, please keep in mind that it should only be used when the integrated router of Next.js can't meet your app requirements. A custom server will remove important performance optimizations, like serverless functions and Automatic Static Optimization.
A custom server cannot be deployed on Vercel.
Standalone output mode, does not trace custom server files and this mode outputs a separate minimal server.js file instead.
source: https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-nextjs
